# How to store one or many checkbox values in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

As this question is sure to reveal, I'm relatively new to database design.  Please pardon my lack of understanding.

I want to store values like the following (example from Google calendar) in a database:

[image: Google Calendar repeating events]

What's the best way to do this?  Would this be one database field or several?

If the former, does this disobey normalization rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a relation many-many, you can achive that separating the columns in more logical way (normalization) ... for the example above:

You should have a table called "schedules"(or whatever make sense to you),  another something like "repeat_on" and a third table called "days"(here you have monday-sunday with their IDs). In the table of the middle(repeat_on) you should create foreign keys(for the other 2 tables: schedule_id and day_id) to do the magic.

This way you can combine whatever you want, for example:

```
schedule    day
 1           1
 1           3
 1           7
```

Meaning that you have to do the same on monday, wednesday and sunday.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, normalization is an art. However, I usually take fields like your example and keep them in one table as we will never have more than 7 days. However, if there is any chance of growth I would put it in a separate table.

Comment: IMO, normalization is more craft than art.

Answer (score 0):

If the options are mutually exclusive, then you can use one field to store the choice. Ideally set up constraints for the field such that only the allowed values can be stored.

If more than one option can be chosen, you should have one field per option, with values 'y' and 'n' (or 't'/'f' for true/false). Again, you should add a constraint to only allow these values. If you DBMS supports it, use a BIT datatype, which only allows 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overblown for your example, but you may want to look at the following article:

http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf

I know this is an indirect answer but couldn't hurt to read.

Answer (score 0):

Something like days of the week is tricky.  PachinSV and Dustin Laine both make good points.  If you have a list of things to choose from, having a code table to list the things and an intersection table to say which ones are chosen is a good basic design.

The reason days of the week are tricky is that the domain (i.e. list of days) is pretty small and there is no way the domain will ever expand.  Also, one of the advantages of the intersection table approach is that you can run a query against everything that happens on a Wednesday (for example).  This is great when your code table is something like category tags for blog articles, since asking to see everything with the tag "How-To" is a reasonable question.  For the case of days of the week recurrence, does it make any actual business sense to say show me everything that recurs on Wednesdays?  I don't think so.  For sure you'll query on dates and date ranges, but days of the week, and only in the context of recurrence?  I can't think of a practical reason to do that.

Therefore, there is an argument to be made that the days of the week are attributes and not independent entities so having seven bit flags on your table is still 3NF.